# Python: Writing Images and dataframes to the same excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm creating an excel dashboard and I want to generate an excel workbook that has some dataframes on half of the sheets, and .png files for the other half.  I'm having difficulty writing them to the same file in one go.  Here's what I currently have.  It seems that when I run my for loop, it won't let me add additional worksheets.  Any advice on how I might get my image files added to this workbook?  I can't find anything about why I can't add any more worksheets Thanks!

```
dfs = dict()
dfs['AvgVisitsData'] = avgvisits
dfs['F2FCountsData'] = f2fcounts

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("MyData.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
for name, df in dfs.items():
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name, index = False)
```

Then I want to add a couple sheets with some images to the same excel workbook.  Something like this, but where I'm not creating a whole new workbook.

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('MyData.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('image1')
worksheet.insert_image('A1', 'MemberCollateral.png')
```

Anyone have any tips to work around this?

Comment: What isn't working? This looks like you're creating a second workbook.

Comment: @mauve Right.  I want to keep adding onto my initial MyData.xlsx file.  I was just using the second block of code as an example.  How would you do the first block of code THEN add the MemberCollateral.png file on a new worksheet?

Comment: You should be able to access the workbook through `writer.book` attribute.

Comment: @mauve Do you have any links that I could look at that might be useful?

Comment: try with `writer.sheets['your sheet name'].insert_image(...)`

Comment: @mauve  I'm not having any luck, and I experimented with the syntax.  I guess the heart of this question is... Is it possible to write an image file with the writer = pd.ExcelWriter("MyData.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') 

Or... 

Is it possible to write a pandas dataframe with  workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses03.xlsx')
 worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

Comment: what do you mean by workaround? your code should work as long as you don't create another workbook. What is the issue here?

Comment: See [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) in the XlsxWriter docs for examples of getting a handle to a workbook or worksheet after creating them with Pandas.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get a handle to the underlying XlsxWriter workbook and worksheet objects and insert an image:

```
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_image.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Insert an image.
worksheet.insert_image('D3', 'logo.png')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

See also [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) in the XlsxWriter docs for more examples

Comment: Great answer! One quick comment: your `workbook  = writer.book` is not needed

Comment: I know but I always include it in the Pandas XlsxWriter examples so people  can see how to access it case they need to.

Comment: this only worked for me if I called writer.book.close() instead of writer.save().  using writer.save() resulted in a corrupt excel file, but writer.book.close() worked.

Comment: @justin cress. I don't see any issues. I reran the example above and it worked and the file opened without issue. I also upgraded to the latest Pandas to make sure. If you think there is an issue then you should open a Pandas github issue with an example that demonstrates it.

Comment: I needed to install the xlsxwriter module in addition to Pandas but didn't have to import xlsxwriter. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes. That is normal. Pandas will use xlsxwriter or openpyxl if either one is available.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I came up with.  I still cound't find a way to do this without re-importing the workbook with `load_workbook` but this got the job done.

```
# assign dataframes to dictionary and export them to excel
avgvisits = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql(avgvisits(), cnxn))
f2fcounts = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql(f2fcounts(), cnxn))
activityencounters = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql(ActivityEncounters(), cnxn))
activityencountersp = activityencounters.pivot_table(values='ActivityCount', index = ['Activity'], columns= ['QuarterYear'], aggfunc=np.max)

dfs = dict()
dfs['AvgVisitsData'] = avgvisits
dfs['F2FIndirect'] = f2fcounts
dfs['ActivityEncounters'] = activityencountersp

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("MyData.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
for name, df in dfs.items():
    if name != 'ActivityEncounters':
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name, index=False)
    else:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name, index=True)

writer.save()
writer.close()

# re-import the excel book and add the graph image files
wb = load_workbook('MyData.xlsx')
png_loc = 'MemberCollateral.png'
wb.create_sheet('MemberCollateralGraph')
ws = wb['MemberCollateralGraph']
my_png = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(png_loc)
ws.add_image(my_png, 'A1')

png_loc = 'DirectIndirect.png'
ws = wb['F2FIndirect']
my_png = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(png_loc)
ws.add_image(my_png, 'A10')

png_loc = 'QuarterlyActivitySummary.png'
ws = wb['ActivityEncounters']
my_png = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(png_loc)
ws.add_image(my_png, 'A10')
wb.save('MyData.xlsx')
```