# Export multiple boxplots into existing excel (Python, pandas, matplotlib)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

How can you put multiple boxplots into an existing excel file ? I already put in a dataframe into the "Describe.xlsx" sheet.

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df_desc = df.describe()
df_desc.to_excel("Describe.xlsx", index_label = True)
```

Here i make a boxplot for every column in the dataframe:

```
for column in df1:
    plt.figure()
    df1.boxplot([column], showfliers =False)
```

I want to put every boxplot into the existing sheet "Describe.xlsx" How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Writing Images and dataframes to the same excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601031/python-writing-images-and-dataframes-to-the-same-excel-file)

Comment: No not really :/