# writing image to excel with xlsxwriter returns " workbook not callable"

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Using the first answer to the following link [Python: Writing Images and dataframes to the same excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601031/python-writing-images-and-dataframes-to-the-same-excel-file) as a guide:

I have the following script in which I like to write a dataframe object to one sheet and a bunch of images to another sheet.

```
class name():

 def some_func(self):
     self.writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Name1',engine='xlsxwriter')
     return
 
 def write_excel(self):
     self.df.to_excel(self.writer,sheet_name='Name',index=False, header=False)
     self.writer.save()   
    return

def write_excel(self):
    self.workbook = self.writer.book('Name1')
    self.worksheet = self.writer.sheets(name='images')
    images=[]
    do some stuff
    for i,image in enumerate(images):
        self.worksheet.insert_image('D1',0,y_postn[i],image)  
    self.writer.save()   
    return
```

It returns the following error

```
'Workbook' object is not callable
```

Not sure how to interpret this error or fix it?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
self.workbook = self.writer.book('Name1')
```

Book is an object, not a method and it has the following fields (`__call__` is not one of them):

```
_Workbook__active_sheet
_Workbook__all_fonts_num_formats_xf_styles_rec
_Workbook__all_links_rec
_Workbook__backup_on_save
_Workbook__backup_rec
_Workbook__bof_rec
_Workbook__bookbool_rec
_Workbook__boundsheets_rec
_Workbook__codepage_rec
_Workbook__country_code
_Workbook__country_rec
_Workbook__custom_palette_b8
_Workbook__datemode_rec
_Workbook__dates_1904
_Workbook__dsf_rec
_Workbook__eof_rec
_Workbook__ext_sst_rec
_Workbook__first_tab_index
_Workbook__fngroupcount_rec
_Workbook__height_twips
_Workbook__hide_obj_rec
_Workbook__hpos_twips
_Workbook__hscroll_visible
_Workbook__intf_end_rec
_Workbook__intf_hdr_rec
_Workbook__intf_mms_rec
_Workbook__obj_protect
_Workbook__obj_protect_rec
_Workbook__owner
_Workbook__palette_rec
_Workbook__password_rec
_Workbook__precision_rec
_Workbook__prot4rev_pass_rec
_Workbook__prot4rev_rec
_Workbook__protect
_Workbook__protect_rec
_Workbook__refresh_all_rec
_Workbook__selected_tabs
_Workbook__sheet_refs
_Workbook__sst
_Workbook__sst_rec
_Workbook__styles
_Workbook__tab_width_twips
_Workbook__tabid_rec
_Workbook__tabs_visible
_Workbook__use_cell_values
_Workbook__useselfs_rec
_Workbook__vpos_twips
_Workbook__vscroll_visible
_Workbook__width_twips
_Workbook__window1_rec
_Workbook__wnd_hidden
_Workbook__wnd_mini
_Workbook__wnd_protect
_Workbook__wnd_protect_rec
_Workbook__worksheet_idx_from_name
_Workbook__worksheets
_Workbook__write_access_rec
__class__
__delattr__
__dict__
__dir__
__doc__
__eq__
__format__
__ge__
__getattribute__
__gt__
__hash__
__init__
__init_subclass__
__le__
__lt__
__module__
__ne__
__new__
__reduce__
__reduce_ex__
__repr__
__setattr__
__sizeof__
__str__
__subclasshook__
__weakref__
_get_supbook_index
_ownbook_supbook_ref
_ownbook_supbookx
_supbook_xref
_xcall_supbook_ref
_xcall_supbookx
_xcall_xref
active_sheet
add_font
add_rt
add_sheet
add_sheet_reference
add_str
add_style
backup_on_save
convert_sheetindex
country_code
dates_1904
default_style
del_str
encoding
get_active_sheet
get_backup_on_save
get_biff_data
get_country_code
get_dates_1904
get_default_style
get_height
get_hpos
get_hscroll_visible
get_obj_protect
get_owner
get_protect
get_sheet
get_style_stats
get_tab_width
get_tabs_visible
get_use_cell_values
get_vpos
get_vscroll_visible
get_width
get_wnd_mini
get_wnd_protect
get_wnd_visible
height
hpos
hscroll_visible
obj_protect
owner
protect
raise_bad_sheetname
rt_index
save
set_active_sheet
set_backup_on_save
set_colour_RGB
set_country_code
set_dates_1904
set_height
set_hpos
set_hscroll_visible
set_obj_protect
set_owner
set_protect
set_tab_width
set_tabs_visible
set_use_cell_values
set_vpos
set_vscroll_visible
set_width
set_wnd_mini
set_wnd_protect
set_wnd_visible
setup_ownbook
setup_xcall
sheet_index
str_index
tab_width
tabs_visible
use_cell_values
vpos
vscroll_visible
width
wnd_mini
wnd_protect
wnd_visible
```

Here's the official example for how to use this API:

```py
# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

# Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
chart.add_series({'values': ['Sheet1', 1, 1, max_row, 1]})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart(1, 3, chart)
```

You are not supposed to call workbooks or sheets as if they are functions. You access functions within them such as `.add_chart` or `.insert_chart`.

How do you get your hands on a spreadsheet with books and sheets in it in the first place? Like this:

```
# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
```

You also have the option of accessing the xlswriter APIs directly without going through pandas (but I don't see why you would in your particular case):

```py
workbook  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
```

Have a look at the [official documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) - it's full of clear examples.

Comment: ok I removed ('Name1') but now I get the following error 'dict' object is not callable for line ' self.worksheet = self.writer.sheets(name='images')'

Comment: it's exactly the same issue - you are trying to call something which is not a function. what are you trying to achieve with this statement anyway?

Comment: I had mistakenly used round brackets instead of square bracket. Apologies for the simple error. Thanks for the clarity on the terminology.